# Reading location of joint and timestamp

Tags: c#, variables, kinect, kinect-sdk

If I want to read and store the data/value obtained to a variable, about a skeleton joint in real-time using the Kinect Sensor, how would I do that?

How do I save that data/value to a variable that won't update unless I ask for a new value. I want to be able to keep the values I get in different variables.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is too vague, what are you trying to do (even in pseudo-code) and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

It would be no different then saving any other variable type.

```
JointCollection _savedJoint;
DateTime _savedJointTime;

private void OnSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
    {
        if (skeletonFrame == null || skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength == 0)
            return;

        // resize the skeletons array if needed
        if (_skeletons.Length != skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength)
            _skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];

        // get the skeleton data
        skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(_skeletons);

        foreach (var skeleton in _skeletons)
        {
            // skip the skeleton if it is not being tracked
            if (skeleton.TrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                continue;

            // do other checks and actions if needed...

            // save off the joint
            _savedJoint = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft];
            _savedJointTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to save off multiple joints, you can create an array.  If you want to package everything together you can create a class that stores everything.

Comment: wont that update the value saved each time it gets new data?? I want to keep the old data from, for example, the 2nd set of data obtained, and one from the 5th set of data or.............. save each set of data separately so if I have 10 frames of data, I get 10 different sets of data saved (1 through 10)

Comment: Add an `if` statement to only save the values under a certain condition (e.g., `if (_counter % 5 == 0)` for every 5th update) or any other way you want to limit the number of updates that are recorded.  Or, use the `streamType.OpenNextFrame()` function to poll any of the 3 streams for the next available frame -- set up a timer to decide when to call it.